# Https certificate Error in the URL without WWW

Tags: apache, tomcat

I have hosted the site in AWS Apache Tomcat/7.0.47.and implemented SSL in it.
Now,
HTTPS working fine if I enter **www.example.com**.
But ,if I enter **example.com** in browser https certificate shows its unverified. 
What i need to do to solve this issue ?
if URL redirection helps ,what is the **unix command** for Redirection ?!

Comment: Hi, can you give me the steps on how did you implement SSL in tomcat?
Because it's not working for me.
I did:
1.generate key
2.generate csr send to ca and request a cert
3.get files
4.import to keystore
5.configure the server.xml

After that, https is working but it displays connection not secure.
My url looks like this

laptap.partner.solution

Answer (score 0):

You will need a certificate that is valid for both domains. 
See here for details: 
https://serverfault.com/questions/447222/ssl-certificates-for-domain-without-www